# How can I force Rails to load all models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

Rails does model loading on demand.  For a rake task that I'm writing, I need to be able to iterate over all `ActiveRecord::Base` instances (which is possible with `ActiveRecord::Base.send(:subclasses)`).

However, for the above to work, they have to already be loaded.  Anyone know of a way to force all models to load?  Ideally I'd like to not have to poke through `app/models` since I'd like to catch models added by plugins as well.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

rails 2:

```
Dir[Pathname(RAILS_ROOT) + 'app/models/**/*.rb'].each do |path|
  require path
end
```

rails 3:

```
Dir[Rails.root + 'app/models/**/*.rb'].each do |path|
  require path
end
```

another way:

```
(ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables - %w[schema_migrations]).each do |table|
  table.classify.constantize rescue nil
end
```

Comment: Problem with that is that, as noted in the question, that won't catch models added by plugins.  In concrete terms, one of the important cases for the plugin I'm writing is a Spree shop, where basically none of the models are in `app/models`

Comment: Just add `**/` at begining of glob => `Dir[Rails.root + '**/app/models/**/*.rb']`

Comment: Though, why do you need to go through all models?

Comment: It's a tool that basically build a graph out of all of the :has_many relationships, basically and then lets those be queried in interesting ways.

Comment: Ok I added another way which uses tables (it will not load STI models)

Comment: Note that `Rails.root` has been available in Rails 2 for quite a while.

Comment: Do you know from which version I can use `Rails.root`?

Comment: Not off the top of my head. Try it. If it works, then great and if it doesn't then use `RAILS_ROOT` instead.

Comment: This is not a 100% reliable method, for a few reasons.

One of them is that if there are other methods declared elsewhere (e.g. vendor), it's not going to catch them.

Comment: `Dir[Rails.root + 'app/models/**/*.rb'].each do |path|
  require path
end` tried the rails 3 option. but it breaks the rails dynamic loader. as if you reload! it not picks up your up to date changes.

Answer (score 54):

I needed all models loaded for a rake task that checks the validity of all records, and found the handy method [`eager_load`](http://apidock.com/rails/Rails/Application/eager_load!), which can be used simply like so:

`Rails.application.eager_load!`

Comment: I really prefer this answer to the others. It's a much cleaner way to do things in my opinion.

Comment: @taelor I second that. It takes care of much more potential issues.

Comment: As a note this doesn't work in Rails 6.0, even if `Rails.application.config.eager_load = true` is set.

Comment: Works for STI. Other methods didn't.

Answer (score 0):

rails 7.0

```
Rails.initialize!
```

Will actually load all the models and anything you could need.

Works fine for `.rake` files (rails cli commands) too.

Comment: I get error: Application has been already initialized.