# Why is #constants returning an empty array?

Tags: ruby

Given a class construction like this:

```
class Notifiers::NotifierBase
  def initialize
  end

end

module Notifiers
  module Profile
    class TipNotifier < NotifierBase
    end
  end
end
```

When I run `Notifiers::Profile.constants` `[]` is returned. Shouldn't I see the class constant `TipNotifier`?

If I call `Notifiers::Profile::TipNotifier`, then if I call `Notifiers::Profile.constants`, I get this object return as part of the array. `[:TipNotifier]`. What am I missing here?

Maybe I should add that these samples are in files included as part of the global namespace in a Rails project. `BaseNotifier` is part of the global namespace.

Comment: your code samples are disconnected. Where is `BaseNotifier` ? Give the proper information..to help you out.

Comment: Cannot see `Notifiers` defined anywhere, and you have `NotifierBase` *and* `BaseNotifier` in your example. It's not clear whether that's part of your problem, or just a typo in the question.

Comment: sorry I forgot the notifiers module

Comment: Your code as written is broken, you're defining `BaseNotifier` and inheriting from `NotifierBase`.

Comment: I get `[:TipNotifier]` as expected (assuming matching base-class name). Is your output from debug code within the app, and it is possible your first call is made before the file containing the later definition is `require`d? What happens if you just put your code snippet above into a file, along with `p Notifiers::Profile.constants` ?

Comment: Ok. I've updated again. It is still giving me this output.

Comment: you are having the same names as class as well as modules.

Comment: I have this file auto-loading in Rails. If I copy-paste directly into irb. Works fine. Must be a rails autoloading config issue?

Comment: @Paul: Yes, I expect file is not loaded for your first command. I'm not sure how the autoloading works in Rails, but that is probably part of the answer.

Comment: That appears to be my answer. Rails loads on-demand. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245838/how-can-i-force-rails-to-load-all-models