# Load all models of a gem programmatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, module, rubygems

It turn out models of gem does not load on start up, when it is being called it loads that model specifically but for my requirement I need to load all of them on start up but I could not find a way to do that searching around.

So, in one line, I want to (forcefully) load all models of a gem grammatically. What is the right way to do that?

Comment: Show the code you use to load the models, will make the question easier to understand.

Comment: Which gem(s) are you talking about? How do you see that it does not load on startup?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I force Rails to load all models?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245838/how-can-i-force-rails-to-load-all-models)